# ASP.NET: The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been trying to get a `progressBar` into my `GridView` for a while now. Unfortunately without success. I currently have the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShow" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Progress" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Progress" HeaderText="Progress" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="lbProgress" runat="server" Text="<div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='<%#Eval("Progress") %>' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'><span class='sr-only'>60% Complete</span></div></div>"></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

which results in a *parser error* (The server tag is not well formed.). If I replace the eval with any value it works without any issues. I think I am missing something here but I really can't find it.

Comment: Why are you using Literal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason all of your markup is as text of Literal control. So you have the problem with quotes, as you need double quotes for `Text=""` and of `Eval`.

Personally I see no reason to use Literal here, you can just use the markup as is, and the problem will go away:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class='progress'>
        <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='<%#Eval("Progress") %>' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'>
            <span class='sr-only'>60% Complete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some reason I thought that ItemTemplate expected a ASP control. And escaping those quotes was very difficult.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use Eval method instead of Text Method.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<div class='progress'>
    <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='<%#Eval("Progress") %>' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'>
        <span class='sr-only'>60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```